# c++ special method visibility

Tags: c++, private, friend, public, protected

I have a simple object, of type "ObjectX", with a simple method called "doSomething()". I'd like to make doSomething ONLY accessable by other ObjectX's. In other words, if something that is either static, or not an object of type "ObjectX" tries to call doSomething, it will be unable to. However, if an object of type ObjectX tries to call the method, it WILL be able to.

This differs from a private method, in that, a private method can only be called from the same object it is in. If there were another object of the same type calling that method on a different object, it would be locked out.

Comment: No, a private method is not limited to being called from the same object. Another object of the same type _can_ use it, it wont' be locked out.

Comment: @Seth Ooh, really? My mistake then! You should write that as an answer, I would be happy to accept :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`private` does almost exactly what you want. Only objects of the same type can use `private` methods, and other objects can call those functions on other objects (that is, `private` functions are not restricted to the invoking object).

The only thing that is not as you described is that that `static` functions in the same class can also use `private` functions. There is no language feature that lets you restrict a function to the object only (excluding `static` functions).

Comment: When you say that static methods can access it... Does this mean that ALL static methods can access it, or is it limited to static methods inside the same class?

Comment: @GeorgesOatesLarsen static functions in the same class.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where you get your facts. A private function `A::foo` can be called by any object of type `A`. Be it on itself or on another instance.

```
class A
{
public:
  void foo(const A& other) { other.priv(); }

private:
  void priv() const {}
};


int main()
{
  A a1, a2;
  a1.foo(a2);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++

```
Class A{
  A a;
  doSomething(){
    a.doSomething();
  }
}
```

The above code would work.And this is the reason copy constructor work.

```
Class B{
  A a;
  doSomethingElse(){
    a.doSomething();
  }
}
```

Above would not anyways work.

If you want to provide access to B as well make A a friend of B by specifying `friend B;` in class A.